# nao consigo entrar na função success json

Tags: php, ajax, json

Dai galera....não estou conseguindo passar o retorno do meu codigo para a função 
success do meu ajax via json....estou usando codeiginiter, php, mysql....alguem 
pode me socorrer....já faz quase uma semana que estou tentando e não desempaco...

Meu controller....

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
public function index() {
    $dados['tituloPrincipal'] = 'Login';
    $this->load->view('Listar/login', $dados);
}
public function cadastroLogin() {
    $dados['nomeCliente'] = $this->input->post('nomeCliente');
    $dados['telefoneCliente'] = $this->input->post('telefoneCliente');
    $dados['senhaCliente'] = $this->input->post('senhaCliente');
    $dados['emailCliente'] = $this->input->post('emailCliente');
    $this->load->model("mLogin");
    $result = $this->mLogin->cadastrandoLogin($dados);
    $msg['success'] = false;
    if ($result) {
        $msg['success'] = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($msg);
}
```

}

Meu Model....

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}
public function cadastrandoLogin($dados = null) {
    if ($dados != null) {            
        $this->db->insert('clientes', $dados);
    }
    try {
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Meu script.....

```
$(function () {
$('#adicionarCliente').click(function () {
    var data = $('#cadastroCliente').serialize();
    if ((nomeCliente && emailCliente && telefoneCliente && senhaCliente) != null) {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>Login/cadastroLogin',
            data: data, //Dados
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    alert(response);
                    //ajax_redirect('<?php echo base_url() ?>Login');
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Lasco");
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Lascado');
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: `Lascô` não `Lasco`; `lascô` tá no pretérito perfeito (apesar de ser um uso menos formal com marcas de oralidade) e indica surpresa desagradável, já `lasco` está no presente e indica o hábito em lascar alguém, como se fosse uma ameaça ou _hobby_

Comment: Eu creio que se você colocar o método `complete` você consiga mais informações para depuração, como de repente erro 500 no lado do servidor; vide http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, mas não entendi este método complete...pode me dar um exemplo??

Comment: **complete** Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus ) A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "nocontent", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"). As of jQuery 1.5, the complete setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event. (Da documentação linkada)

Comment: Você usa como o `success`, mas garante que sempre executa após o final do retorno do servidor. O `success` só é executado em caso de sucesso